# Insert with select subquery using SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

I am having a problem when using an INSERT statement with a nested select. The query works when executing it in the SQLManagement Studio but returns an error when executing it in code.

The query looks like :

```
INSERT INTO [Projects] 
     VALUES ('1', 'None', '2', '2010/09/08 10:36:30 AM', 4, 1, 4, '6', '', 'n/a', 'no', 'n/a', 'None', 0, 'n/a', 'n/a', 'no', 'A3', 'no', 'Blnk', 'aa',
  (SELECT status.statusID from status where name = 'STOPPED')
```

)

The error returned :

```
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed
```

Is there an explanation for this and how will go to solve this issue as I do not know what the id of the Status is, besides executing a separate select query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this...

```
INSERT INTO [Projects] 
SELECT '1', 'None', '2', '2010/09/08 10:36:30 AM', 4, 1, 4, '6', '', 'n/a', 'no', 'n/a', 'None', 0, 'n/a', 'n/a', 'no', 'A3', 'no', 'Blnk', 'aa',
status.statusID from status where name = 'STOPPED'
```

The error makes sense because you could have multiple rows from the sub query. In my suggestion, you could also end up with multiple rows too. Should there be more to the filter?

Comment: Thanks now I see why the error is thrown, there isn't really anything else to filter on. I was kinda going on the assumption that the select would only return 1 value

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create Stored Procedure.

```
declare @statusID int;

SELECT @statusID=status.statusID from status where name = 'STOPPED'

INSERT INTO [Projects] 
     VALUES ('1', 'None', '2', '2010/09/08 10:36:30 AM', 4, 1, 4, '6', '', 'n/a', 'no', 'n/a', 'None', 0, 'n/a', 'n/a', 'no', 'A3', 'no', 'Blnk', 'aa',@statusID);
```